# Scrolling Not working when keyboard open in android

Tags: android

I have made a layout. When I start to enter the login credential then keyboard appear and now i am not able to scroll to fill the other details. So all the views hide behind the keyboard. Please help me fix this so that when keyboard open then it should start the scrolling to see other views

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/login_bg" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="hideKeyboard" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/top_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/blank_header"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/top_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/login_font" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:onClick="hideKeyboard" >

        <Utility.LoginRL
            android:id="@+id/scrollview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
            android:onClick="hideKeyboard"
            android:scrollbars="none" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/logo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:onClick="hideKeyboard"
                    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/user_pass_layout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/logo"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
                    android:layout_margin="5dip">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/username_layout"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/user_text1"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:onClick="showKeyboard"
                        android:paddingBottom="20dp" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:text="User Name"
                            android:textColor="#9D9D9D"
                            android:textSize="20dp" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/uName"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:background="#00000000"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#228ED3"
                            android:textSize="20dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/password_layout"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/username_layout"
                        android:background="@drawable/user_text2"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:onClick="showKeyboard"
                        android:layout_margin="5dip"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:onClick="showKeyboard"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="5dp"
                            android:text="Password"
                            android:textColor="#9D9D9D"
                            android:textSize="20dp" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/pass"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:background="#00000000"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:password="true"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#228ED3"
                            android:textSize="20dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>

                <!--
             <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/site_url_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/user_pass_layout"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp" >



                -->

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lbl_siteUrl"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/user_pass_layout"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/site_url1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:onClick="showKeyboard"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dip"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Site Url"
                    android:textColor="#9D9D9D"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/siteUrl"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/lbl_siteUrl"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/site_url2"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="http://"
                    android:textColor="#228ED3"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />
                <!-- </LinearLayout> -->

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/login_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/siteUrl"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/login_btn" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/forgot_pass_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/login_btn"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/forgot_pass_btn" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </Utility.LoginRL>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

LoginRL

public class LoginRL extends ScrollView {
        public boolean isKeyboardHidden = true;

```
    public LoginRL(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public LoginRL(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public LoginRL(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        final int proposedheight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        final int actualHeight = getHeight();

        if (actualHeight > proposedheight){
            isKeyboardHidden = false;
            //LoginScreen.keyboardToolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            isKeyboardHidden = true;
            //LoginScreen.keyboardToolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

Comment: V will be your parent view. It may be your root layout.

Comment: You did not understand my question. Please read again...When keyboard open then layout should move upward and it should start scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your layout inside a `ScrollView` and you will be able to scroll when the keyboard is shown.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="hideKeyboard" >

   .......

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I have tried but still not scrolling when keyboard open..Bottom views hide behind the keyboard